# Changes in JAR task from Gradle 1.7 to 4.1

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I have a project which is currently built using Gradle version 1.7 and I'm trying to move to version 4.1 as builds are much faster and dependencies can be downloaded in parallel. However I'm seeing some weird behaviour that I don't quite understand.  I have a build.gradle file for a couple of sub projects that overrides the main classes task of the java plugin.  In it it runs an ant task that generates classes in the build directory.

```
task classes(overwrite: true) {
  inputs.dir project.ext.inputsPath
  outputs.dir "${project.buildDir}/classes/main"
  doLast {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xmlbean', classname: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean', classpath: configurations.compile.asPath)
    ant.xmlbean(srcgendir: "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/xmlbeans",
                classgendir: "${project.buildDir}/classes/main",
                javasource: '1.5',
                failonerror: true,
                includeAntRuntime: false,
                classpath: project.configurations.compile.asPath) {
        fileset(dir: schemaPath, includes: project.ext.has('inclusionPattern') ? project.ext.inclusionPattern : '*.xsd')
    }
  }
}
```

This all works as expected and I get classes generated in `{ project_dir }/build/classes/main`

This is the output i get from the console

```
> Task :my-task:classes
  Putting task artifact state for task ':my-task:classes' into context took 0.0 secs.
  Executing task ':my-task:classes' (up-to-date check took 0.002 secs) due to:
  [ant:xmlbean] Time to build schema type system: 0.616 seconds
  [ant:xmlbean] Time to generate code: 1.512 seconds
  [ant:xmlbean] Compiling 226 source files to E:\Development\my-task\build\classes\main

  [ant:xmlbean] 4 warnings

> Task :my-task:classes
  [ant:xmlbean] Time to compile code: 6.263 seconds

  :my-task:classes (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 8.899 secs.
  :my-task:jar (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :my-task:jar
  Putting task artifact state for task ':my-task:jar' into context took 0.0 secs.
  Executing task ':my-task:jar' (up-to-date check took 0.004 secs) due to:
  Output property 'archivePath' file E:\Development\my-task\build\libs\my-task.jar has changed.

  :my-task:jar (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.012 secs.
  :my-task:install (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :my-task:install
```

The classes task seems to run twice (not sure if this makes any difference) with the task that runs ant running first. As mentioned earlier I do get classes generated by the ant task.

My problem is that the behaviour between Gradle 1.7 -> 4.1 seems to have changed (As you would expect it to) in that for some reason when the jar task runs my classes inside build/classes/main are not archived into the jar, i just get a blank manifest file.  How do I get these classes generated using the ant task into the Jar using the default jar task?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you overriding the `classes` task? The normal approach would be to create an additional task which writes to a new directory and wire it into the DAG

eg:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task xmlBeanClasses {
   def inclusionPattern = project.ext.has('inclusionPattern') ? project.ext.inclusionPattern : '*.xsd'
   inputs.property 'inclusionPattern', inclusionPattern 
   inputs.dir project.ext.inputsPath
   inputs.dir schemaPath
   outputs.dir "$buildDir/classes/xmlbeans"
   outputs.dir "$buildDir/generated-sources/xmlbeans"
   doLast { 
      // TODO: generate classes in $buildDir/classes/xmlbeans
   }
}

// wire the new task into the DAG
classes.dependsOn xmlBeanClasses

// add the generated classes dir to the "main" classesDirs
// (this dir will now be included in the jar etc)
sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.add files("$buildDir/classes/xmlbeans")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  When I try this gradle throws the error: ClassesDirs does not allow modification.  As to why it was done the way I mentioned in the question, this is a large project that has been touched by many people over many years.  Trying to upgrade gradle without breaking everything.